# Shortctus not working in Code With Me in intellij - Java

Tags: intellij-idea

When in Code With Me in intellij client - java, some of the shortcuts are not working eg. introduce local varialble(⌘ Сmd, ⌥ Opt, V),contants.
is there any way to enable these shortcuts?

Trying to use shortcuts in JetBrians client code with me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with the Code With Me team here at JetBrains.
Can you provide more details about your issue [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=CWM)? Please include what version and what IDE you are using.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CWM-8775/Shortcuts-not-working-in-Code-With-Me-in-IDEA-2023.2.2

Comment: This is resolved after updating the Idea. 
Thanks.